# How do I run a ng-repeat loop inside a table in html?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, single-page-application

```
                <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <th ng-click="sortData('firstname')">
                            Firstname <div ng-class="getSortClass('firstname')"></div>
                        </th>

                        <th ng-click="sortData('lastname')">
                            Lastname <div ng-class="getSortClass('lastname')"></div>
                        </th>


                        <th ng-click="sortData('email')">
                            Email <div ng-class="getSortClass('email')"></div>
                        </th>


                        <th ng-click="sortData('university')">
                            University <div ng-class="getSortClass('university')"></div>
                        </th>

                        <th ng-click="sortData('githublink')">
                            Github Link <div ng-class="getSortClass('githublink')"></div>
                        </th>

                        <th ng-click="sortData('bamboolink')">
                            Bamboo <div ng-class="getSortClass('bamboolink')"></div>
                        </th>

                        <th ng-click="sortData('backendnote')">
                            Backend <div ng-class="getSortClass('backendnote')"></div>
                        </th>

                        <th ng-click="sortData('frontend')">
                            Frontend <div ng-class="getSortClass('frontend')"></div>
                        </th>

                        <th ng-click="sortData('algorithms')">
                            Algorithms <div ng-class="getSortClass('algorithms')"></div>
                        </th>

                        <th ng-click="sortData('specialnote')">
                            Special notes <div ng-class="getSortClass('specialnote')"></div>
                        </th>

                        <th>
                            Extra column1
                        </th>

                        <th>
                            Extra column2
                        </th>

                        <th>
                            Extra column3
                        </th>

                        <th>
                            Delete
                        </th>

                        <th>
                            Edit
                        </th>

                    </tr>

                </thead>
```

I want to replace these extra column 1, 2 and 3 with ng-repeat since the numbers of columns will change eventually. When I tried this piece of code below

```
                        <div ng-repeat="a in emps">
                            <th>
                                {{a.intervieweeExtra[$index].columnname}}
                            </th>
                        </div>
```

it printed nothing. How do I do this in angularjs 1.x? I am new in html and angularjs. I could not find a working solution yet so I am asking this here. Thanks

Comment: `<th ng-repeat="a in emps">{{a.intervieweeExtra[$index].columnname}}</th>` Show us sample of `emps` and expected html result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason for the `<div>` element. You should put the `ng-repeat` directly on the `<th>` element, i.e.:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <!-- Permanent columns -->
            <th></th>
            <th></th>

            <!-- Variable columns -->
            <th ng-repeat="a in emps">{{a.intervieweeExtra[$index].columnname}}</th>

            <!-- Permanent columns -->
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <!-- Permanent columns -->
            <td></td>
            <td></td>

            <!-- Conditional columns -->
            <td ng-repeat="a in emps"></td>

            <!-- Permanent columns -->
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

An identical `ng-repeat` is added to the table-row in the `<tbody>` element to ensure that the rows in the table-header and table-body contain the same number of columns.

I think that you also just want to reference `{{a.intervieweeExtra.columnname}}`, but without knowing your data-structure it's hard to know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed" ng-repeat="row in objArray">
<tr>
<th colspan={{maxCols}}><h2>{{$index+1}} {{row.name}}</h2></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td ng-repeat="array in row.columns">{{array.name}}</td>
</tr>
</table>

please use this for ng-repeat